# String.contains finds a substring but not Pattern.matches?

Tags: java, regex, string, contains

In one of my try/catch blocks, I catch an exception `e`, and this:

`e.toString().contains("this is a substring")` returns `true`

while

`Pattern.matches(".*this is a substring.*", e.toString())` returns `false`

Why does this happen? Including the `.*` as the prefix and suffix for the regex pattern should essentially make these two functions do the same thing right?

Comment: Show use the full `e.toString()` value

Comment: No, it does not have to. Are there newline symbols in your string? What is `e.toString()`?

Comment: ``contains`` does not work with regexes, ``matches`` obviously does. Your "this is a substring" is obviously an example value. What's the real value and does it contain any characters that might be special in a regex context?

Comment: Thanks for the help! I didn't know that newline symbols needed separate treatment!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your input string contains newline symbol(s), `.*` is not enough in `.matches()` that requires a full string match.

Thus, you need a DOTALL modifier:

```
Pattern.matches("(?s).*this is a substring.*", e.toString())
                 ^^^^
```

See the [Java regex reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL):

> In dotall mode, the expression `.` matches any character, including a line terminator. By default this expression does not match line terminators.
>
> Dotall mode can also be enabled via the **embedded flag expression `(?s)`**. (The `s` is a mnemonic for "single-line" mode, which is what this is called in Perl.)

**NOTE**: if you need to check the presence of a literal substring inside a longer string, a `.contains()` method should work faster. Or, if you need a case insensitive `contains`, you may also check [`StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#containsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).

Comment: Can I suggest you call it the "DOTALL embedded flag expression", as it is called [in the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL)?

Comment: I have issues with the Internet connection, I am updating the answer, but it may take time

Comment: Thanks! There were some newline symbols before my substring!